# Flutter Firestore: Streambuilder returning data from different user documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am having a small problem of user data being returned from different docs i.e. when signed in user returns profile data of another account. How do I return user specific data to respective accounts?

My code:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
  final Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> db = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('Profile')
      .doc('Personal details')
      .snapshots();



                     Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text('First name'),
                        SizedBox(width: 40),
                        StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          stream: db,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError)
                              return Text('Something went wrong');
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting)
                              return CircularProgressIndicator();

                            dynamic data = snapshot.data!.data();
                            return Text(data['First name']);
                            // return Text('First name', style: boldFont);
                          },
                        ),
                      ]),
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Last name'),
                      SizedBox(width: 40),
                      StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                        stream: db,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError)
                            return Text('Something went wrong');
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting)
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();

                          dynamic data = snapshot.data!.data();
                          return Text(data['Last name'], style: boldFont);
                          // return Text('Last name', style: boldFont);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

For signing out

```
onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                          errorMessage = '';
                        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                          errorMessage = error.message!;
                        }
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/signIn');
                        setState(() {});
                      }
```

Screenshot of db

[image: firestore db]

Any assistance would be highly appreciated as I've been stuck trying to fix this for two weeks.

NB: I only have a few months with Flutter, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "when signed in user returns profile data of another account."? Are you sure you are signed in with the right account?

Comment: Well, I am being notified that I am signed in (in the debug console) but it seems that on signing in I do not have a way of returning the document that corresponds with the signed in user. There's definitely a step I am missing but not sure where.

Comment: Have you tried to check the value of UID of the authenticated user? Are the values the same?

Comment: Yes Im using ```FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;``` but it's not corresponding with the doc uid of the logged in user.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Can we continue this conversation in another thread sir?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pay more attention to the way you update data to firestore rather than the way you call for data. If it happens that something is wrong with your upload or there is a mixup of generic data being upload, you may end up putting data where they don't belong and therefore getting the wrong data.

Check the upload code first.